# removing a dislocated hair out of one's beard on shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, beard, borer-separating

Is there any prohibition to remove a disconnected beard hair from a beard on Shabbat? In order to remove the hair you still may have to move away other parts of the beard to get to the hair in question.

At first I thought that this might be Borrer (that is, the melacha (forbidden 'labor') of selection), but I'm not too sure that we could call connected hair and disconnected hair a taarovet (mixture)... or could we?

Also, any problems other than borrer?

Comment: If you know you have a disconnect hair, and it bothers you. Can you carry?

Comment: @Ariel, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: @msh210 It was actually a form of an answer :) If you would be carrying, then it would be pretty serious matter to say removing the hair is forbidden on Shabbos.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say there's no problem because you can't *pick* the connected hair. Borrer is when you pick the Psolet (or what you don't want) out of the food (what you do want). It's like picking a shoe that happens to be in the middle of a row of other shoes that are nailed to the floor.

A more Talmudic could-be-proof, is from Mishna [Beitza 23a](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%92_%D7%90):

> רבי יהודה אומר אין מקרדין את הבהמה ביום טוב מפני שעושה חבורה אבל
>   מקרצפין וחכמים אומרים אין מקרדין אף לא מקרצפין

Translation (self-made):

> R' Yehuda says: it's forbidden to Lekared the beast in Yom Tov since
>   it bruises (the beast) but it's allowed to Lekartzef. Chachamim say:
>   both are forbidden.

And the Talmud on that Mishna explains what's `Lekared` and `Lekartzef` and the reasoning of the different opinions:

> תנו רבנן איזהו קרוד ואיזהו קרצוף קרוד קטנים ועושין חבורה קרצוף גדולים
>   ואין עושין חבורה וג' מחלוקות בדבר רבי יהודה סבר דבר שאינו מתכוין אסור
>   מיהו קרוד קטנים ועושין חבורה קרצוף גדולים ואין עושין חבורה ולא גזרינן
>   קרצוף אטו קרוד ורבנן סברי נמי כר' יהודה דבר שאינו מתכוין אסור וגזרינן
>   קרצוף אטו קרוד ור' אלעזר בן עזריה סבר לה כר' שמעון דאמר דבר שאינו
>   מתכוין מותר ובין קרוד ובין קרצוף שרי

Translation (again self-made):

> Tanu Rabanan: what is Kerud and what is Kirtzuf? Kerud - little and
>   bruises (Rashi - combing with an iron comb that has thin teeth),
>   Kirtzuf - big and doesn't bruise (Rashi - combing with a wooden comb
>   that has thick teeth), and three opinions are involved in the
>   disagreement: R' Yehuda thinks that [davar she'eino mitkaven](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%95%D7%9F#.D7.93.D7.99.D7.9F_.D7.93.D7.91.D7.A8_.D7.A9.D7.90.D7.99.D7.A0.D7.95_.D7.9E.D7.AA.D7.9B.D7.95.D7.95.D7.9F_.D7.91.D7.94.D7.9C.D7.9B.D7.95.D7.AA_.D7.A9.D7.91.D7.AA) is
>   forbidden, however that applies to Kerud that has thin teeth and
>   bruises and not to Kirtzuf that has thick teeth and doesn't bruise,
>   and R' Yehuda doesn't decree to prohibit Kirtzuf just because Kerud is
>   forbidden. Rabanan agree with R' Yehuda that davar she'eino mitkaven
>   is forbidden but they do decree Kirtzuf because of Kerud so they
>   forbid both. And R' Elazar Ben Azaria thinks like R' Shimon that said
>   that davar she'eino mitkaven is allowed, thus he allows both Kirtzuf
>   and Kerud.

Since the only thing that apparantly bothers the Tanaim is making a Chabura (bruise) (and the Tosfot also mention Isur Tolesh - tearing of hair), it seems that Borrer isn't a problem. My preassumption here, though, is that this also applies to Shabbat as it applies to Yom Tov (don't have a proof for that yet).

Comment: I read Hebrew pretty well, but have no idea what your quoted texts are saying. I suspect I'm not alone. Would you mind including an explanatory translation in your answer?

Comment: @msh210 I'll do my best as I can't find an online one.

Comment: @msh210 I hope it's more clear now. Please tell me otherwise.